# Apache using multiple domains with SSL in only 1

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, vps

I have an VPS working with apache2. My problem is, i have 2 projects:
1. example.com
2. admin.example.com
I have an SSL certificate (only valid for) example.com
My problem is, when i access to admin.example.com, the web server is serving my the master project(like i access to example.com). Same problem if i access by ip. 
I have 2 virtual host configurated. I'm redirecting to https with the .htaccess file

my example.com conf file:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost example.com:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
            ServerName example.com
            ServerAlias www.example.com
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public"
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.com.crt
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.com.intermediate.ca
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/example.com.key
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSlcX.png)

my admin.example.com conf file

```
<VirtualHost admin.example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName admin.example.com
    ServerAlias www.admin.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin.example.com/public"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Get another SSL certificate with both names.

Comment: Then, when i have 1 ssl for example.com, i cannot use example.org or egm.com in the same vps? How works a shared hosting then?

Comment: You can have as many names as you want, or even use different certificates if you must.

Comment: In a server can have different host with and without certificate, in a varied way. I'm sure of it

Comment: As Michael Hampton says you need a valid certificate for the other domain or you will always get an SSL warning from your favourite browser. Apache will allow you to server as many different names as you want but SSL certificate must much the name of the virtualhost in the servername directive or serveralias, or your favourite browser will complain